# PSD to HTML somehow works, but actually don't. I am a newbie

Tags: css, html, photoshop, psd

I am a newbie and not expert with HTML and CSS.

I decide to do one project in which to take PSD and make it into HTML and CSS.
The file was 900 x 600 images with many layers and elements one above other.

I watched a few tutorials on how this happens, but never found a tutorial with so complex image.

To complete this task I use Brackets and use Live Preview all the time. When I was almost done I decide to run HTML file in some browsers and in all of the the result was the same- awful.

My Questions are:

1. How is possible to guide myself with Chrome Live Preview (Brackets) and everything is fine and still is, but when I open file in IE, Chrome and Safari the things are very very bad?
2. Am I wrong( or very dumb ) to use this very simple method of writing HTML and CSS.

**My HTML look like this (Every div for himself and every div is equal):**

```
<div id="woman">
<img src="/images/woman.png" alt="woman">
</div>

<div id="bgr-small">
<img src="images/bgr-small.png" alt="Beach">
</div>

<div id="lights" >
<img src="images/lights.png" alt="Projectors">
</div>
```

**And my CSS like this (every div have id and modify them by id and positioning them by the method shown below) :**

```
#woman {
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 45px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 3;
}

#bgr-small {
    position: absolute;
    top: 147px;
    bottom: 29px;
    left: 115px;
    right: 106px;
    z-index: 2;    
}

#lights {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 723px;
    left: 183px;
    right: 170px;
}
```

Right now everything in the right position but only in Brackets Live Preview. In whole CSS i only use ***position: absolute;*** . Also I think that the fault is in this ***position: absolute;***

How can I fix this? Where am I wrong? What i do wrong?

Here is a snippet from the PSD:

[Snippet from PSD](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6gd3cimlzcjzur/AAANBcV3AL8BB9gPObw1Yu1ha?dl=0)

[Folder with my HTML/CSS/Images ( Where is my fault?)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p6gd3cimlzcjzur/AAANBcV3AL8BB9gPObw1Yu1ha?dl=0)

Comment: It's really impossible to answer this. How one should write the HTML is equal parts preferences and context. I will say, in general, that absolutely positioning everything is typically not a good solution as it's rather inflexible in terms of different browsers and devices. These days most people prefer *not* to convert PSD to HTML directly, but rather just use the PSD file as a 'rough guide' and ultimate design in HTML instead.

Comment: provide screen shot of psd.  then i will actually know what you are trying to accomplish.  you are putting images inside of div tags?  Why?  You can position those elements without wrapping them inside of divs.  But again, I don't know end result, so I can't answer.  If you are trying to learn tableless web design, view my personal portfolio and look at the sites.

Comment: I add snippet from PSD.

Answer (score 0):

> How is possible to guide myself with Chrome Live Preview (Brackets) and everything is fine and still is, but when I open file in IE, Chrome and Safari the things are very very bad?

I think you should open up the PSD - and use the slice tool.
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/slicing-web-pages.html

You can slice up the image in anyway you want - for example, if you are going to have a web-form (as I see in your screenshot), slice that section of the image in the PSD.

Once you're done slicing - you can save the file as a webpage - and move forward from there.

> Am I wrong( or very dumb ) to use this very simple method of writing HTML and CSS.

You're not necessarily wrong, but I'd say its no where close to being the standard way of doing things. At least not anymore. As DA stated in the comments, PSDs are now generally used only as rough guides to create the wrappers and website entirely with HTML/CSS/JAVA/etc.

Comment: i understand now that's PSD files are not so used as before, but I have this task and I have to complete it.
I have sliced all images with transparent background and all of them are nice sliced. The main problem is positioning them because honestly I don't know the right way to do this , but i find some way, and obviously is not ok.

Comment: Ok - now use the "Save for web" option in Photoshop to generate the HTML and CSS. Maybe check out this guys answer for some more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903/best-way-to-convert-psd-to-css-html-file?rq=1

Comment: How can I generate HTML and CSS from Save from web? I have all images in png format with transparent background. I already done saving images with Save for web.
The main problem is HTML and CSS that I wrote and maybe my mistakes in positioning  elements.

Comment: "Save for web" should automatically generate the HTML and CSS files for you, along with an "Images" folder, that will contain your slices.